# Why cant i access Django User "status"

Tags: python, html, django

I can't display my custom object "status". I can fill it and see it in my admin. But when i try to get it with HTML it doesn't work. However it does display username, lastname etc. .

Here is my model.py (in accounts):

```
from django.contrib.auth import models as authmodels

class UserZ(authmodels.User,authmodels.PermissionsMixin):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/avatar', null=True, blank=True,default='/static/img/Weramemesicon.png')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

model.py (in posts)

```
User = get_user_model()

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='posts')
    # ...
```

html code:

note: `{{post_user.username}}` workes correct.

```
{% block prepost %}
    <h1>{{post_user.username}}'s Memes</h1>
    {%if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href="{%url 'settings'%}"><p>Einstellungen<p/></a>
    {% endif %}
    {{ post_user.status }}
{% endblock %}
```

my views.py (in posts):

```
class UserPosts(generic.ListView):
    model = models.Post
    template_name = "posts/user_post_list.html"
    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            self.post_user = User.objects.prefetch_related("posts").get(
                username__iexact=self.kwargs.get("username")
            )
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
        else:
            return self.post_user.posts.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["post_user"] = self.post_user
        return context
```

it should display:

```
PeterPan2's Memes

Einstellungen

Some Status
```

Comment: Did you try to read status in console maybe?

Comment: In html it shows an empty <p>...</p>

Comment: Ok but i ask about console. You are sure that u set status for user object? You have blank=True so maybe its just blank.

Comment: please add views code

Comment: Provide views.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreign key is related to `User` model. So `.username` will work. One thing is make foreign key to `UserZ` or do

```
{{ post_user.userz.status }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because your foreign key is to User, not UserZ.

You should not extend the user model like this. UserZ should subclass AbstractUser, not the concrete User class. You should also set the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting to the app and model name - eg "MyApp.UserZ" - and your foreign key from Post should point to that setting, not the class.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a new model `UserZ` by inheriting from django's inbuilt `User` model. But, you haven't defined the model as `AUTH_USER_MODEL`.
The `AUTH_USER_MODEL` may still be `django.contrib.auth.models.User`.

You may need to change the default `AUTH_USER_MODEL` option in `settings.py` to the custom User model. Then, you can access the `status` field in `User` object, like `request.user.status`. But, unless you haven't defined the model as `AUTH_USER_MODEL`, you cannot access the `status` field from `request.user` object.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you send `Post model` object from your `views.py` as `post_user` key.
As Post model contains `User` model as `ForeignKey`, so `{{post_user.username}}` workes correct.

But post model have no connection with UserZ, so it is not working.